How can I compile a C++ program that uses the windows api and is created on my Linux vm machine into an exe that will work on my windows computer
I want to create a small C++ program that pretty much outputs some variable addresses and uses a single windows api function GetCurrentProcessId()
Now my question is how can I compile this program so that I can actually execute it on my windows machine
I'm specifically on a Oracle VM Linux Mint environment and It's my first day using it and the windows api or at least trying to so forgive me if my question is dumb. But I'm fairly sure it hasn't been answered (at least concisely) yet
So first I tried using installing mingw(what I was told to use if I wanted to be able to use winapi header files and compile them on Linux) using sudo apt-get install mingw32  and also sudo apt-get install gcc-mingw-w64
After having those installed I've tried a couple of ways to get my program compiled like i686-w64-mingw32-cpp hack.cpp -o output.exe , x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ hack.cpp -o output.exe which prompted me to install another thing: sudo apt install g++-mingw-w64-x86-64-win32  # version 10.3.0-14ubuntu1+24.3 Mind you most of the things I tried I kept getting the #include <windows.h> no such file or directory error response. But finally after trying x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ hack.cpp -o output.exe It compiled with no errors but when I shared the file to my host windows computer and executed it I got this error output.exe - System Error The code execution cannot proceed because libgcc_s_seh-1.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
After clicking Ok on that I also get the same one but this time it's because of libstdc++-6.dll
Once again, I'm sorry if what I said doesn't make sense I sometimes wish English wasn't my first language so I could have that excuse. I am happy to give any clarifications if needed

The system already told you what the issue is. Which part confuses you?

Install a windows VM or use a Windows docker image (with a full windows dev-env)?  At least that's how I do it the other way around, build an test linux executables on a windows machine

https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-devcontainers-cpp

You just copy those dlls from your compiler installation next to the executable. This is normal.

add -static to the end of your compile args to make those binaries statically linked and not have to copy the extra dlls

There are many GUI frameworks that are cross-platform -- works on multiple platform.  Don't use Windows API, use frameworks like wxWidgets or Qt.

@ThomasMatthews No one mentioned GUIs.

IMHO cross compilation (which is what you are asking about) is usually more of a pain in the neck than it's worth. Much better to just compile natively on each platform you want to support (and stick to using cross platform libraries/APIs rather than platform specific ones).
